# How do I install handbrake cli?

Tags: macos, command-line

I've downloaded the Handbrake CLI. What's the best place to install a command line app on my Mac?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`/usr/local/bin` is meant for installing local (UNIX) software. Conveniently, it is also included in $PATH by default, so you don't need to prefix the full path to run commands installed there.

You do need root access to install/copy files there, you could accomplish this by using `sudo` while moving the binary there.

Answer (score 18):

The best way to install anything on OSX is (IMHO) with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). You can install Homebrew with this command:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then you can install stuff (like `handbrakeCLI`) like this:

```
brew install handbrake
```

Then you can run it straight away from any command prompt with:

```
handbrakeCLI ...
```

Comment: This is out of date (17-03-2017): `brew install handbrake` will install the handbrakecli. After it installs `which handbrakecli` to confirm its existence.

Comment: Currently this installs on Yosemite as `HandBrakeCLI` -- important for those with a case-sensitive file system.

Comment: 15-02-2019 - could not find HandBrakeCLI/handbrakecli in brew, so I installed it via https://handbrake.fr/rotation.php?file=HandBrakeCLI-1.2.0.dmg

Comment: `brew install handbrake` works for me on Catalina. it downloaded `handbrake-1.3.0.catalina.bottle.1.tar.gz`

Comment: `brew cask install handbrake` is the command to install the HandBrake application, but as far as I can tell, it does not also install the command line application (used for scripting batch conversion, etc). That must be downloaded from the link that @Simon provided.